# Conditionally declare service in AndroidManifest

Tags: android, service, manifest, dreamservice, daydream

I have a service, in particular an Android Daydream `DreamService`, that I have declared in my `AndroidManifest.xml` file. When my app is loaded, Android detects this declaration and adds my app as an option to the list of Daydreams the user can choose from in their Settings. I am declaring this `Service` as follows...

```
<service android:name=".daydream.DaydreamService" android:exported="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" >
   <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.service.dreams.DreamService" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   </intent-filter>

   <meta-data
        android:name="android.service.dream"
        android:resource="@xml/daydream" />

</service>
```

I'm trying to see if there is a way I can conditionally load this `Service` declaration programmatically. In other words, I want to only *declare* this `DreamService` based on some programmatic logic. I don't want Android to list or even be aware of my app's Daydream feature unless I programmatically enable it.

**Is something like this possible?**

Comment: Found out after coding you need this permission too <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_DREAM_SERVICE" /> ... just an FYI for all those out there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is something like this possible?

Yes, it is, even without the boldface. :-)

[Call `setComponentEnabledSetting()` on `PackageManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#setComponentEnabledSetting(android.content.ComponentName,%20int,%20int)) to toggle whether or not the component is enabled. Use the `android:enabled` attribute in the manifest to indicate its starting state, where the overall default is that it is enabled.

So, you could add `android:enabled="false"` on your `.daydream.DaydreamService` component to have it be initially disabled, then use `setComponentEnabledSetting()` to enable it later on as needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can also make the component conditional upon a boolean that you declare elsewhere in the resources:

```
<service ...
   android:enabled="@bool/ENABLE_SERVICE">
```

and then you could have ENABLE_SERVICE be set to true in some configurations, but false in others (for example if you only want the service on phone sized screens, not on tablet sized screens).